# trying to send message on whatsapp with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to open web whatsapp but it gives me Deprecation Warning
here is the code

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(20)
driver.quit
```

İts not giving me anything just opens Chrome

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

Comment: Use Whatsapp API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass The `driver_path` to `Service()`. below should work for you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
driver_path = r"chromdriver.exe full file path here"
service = Service(driver_path)
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver  = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options = option )
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(20)
driver.quit
```

Comment: now its just opens chrome but not giving any error just opens chrome not going for whatsapp and not quits

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

Comment: driver_path should be chromdriver.exe, You can download the latest from here https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Answer (score 0):

First you need download chromedriver - https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

ser = Service('path_to\chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)
browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
browser.maximize_window()
time.sleep(20)
browser.quit
```

Comment: it is working with this way but everytime it opens web whatsapp I should open my phone and read the QR code and if I do it the code breaks

Comment: may be browser closed in line "browser.quit" after 20s? Provide error message. In general, it is better to use the API for these purposes.